# How to store user information in relational database using Amazon AWS for Facebook Login in Android

Tags: android, facebook, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-s3

I am currently developing an Android app and have a Facebook login up and running. What I am trying to do next is store the user information in a relation database service in Amazon AWS. I have set up an instance on Amazon and from previous research, I am under the impression a user pool needs to be created to store the user information, but 1. I am not quite sure this is the case and 2. I am not sure how to actually use the user pool once set up. I also see Cognito sync can be used, but again integrating this with Facebook on Android is not something I am aware of doing nor can I find the resources or information online for doing it. Once the user has logged in via Facebook, I would like to store their name and email and gain access to their friend's list.

My below code shows the main part of my Facebook login.java file:

```
if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
        RequestData();
        share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        destinations.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                destinations.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                profile.setProfileId(null);
            }
        }
    });

    share.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().build();
            shareDialog.show(content);

        }
    });

    destinations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectDestination.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectDestination.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

            if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
                RequestData();
                share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                destinations.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("Cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            System.out.println("Cancelled");
        }
    });

}
public void RequestData(){
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
            try {
                if(json != null){
                    String text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");
                    details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                    profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I have added the following to my Build.app gradle file as I believe they may be needed:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ec2:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sdb:2.+'
```

I also added the following dependencies to my AndroidManifestxml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupid>com.amazonaws</groupid>
        <artifactid>aws-android-sdk-core</artifactid>
        <version>[2.2.0, 2.3)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupid>com.amazonaws</groupid>
        <artifactid>aws-android-sdk-cognito</artifactid>
        <version>[2.2.0, 2.3)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupid>com.amazonaws</groupid>
        <artifactid>aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics</artifactid>
        <version>[2.2.0, 2.3)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupid>com.amazonaws</groupid>
        <artifactid>aws-android-sdk-sqs</artifactid>
        <version>[2.2.0, 2.3)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupid>com.amazonaws</groupid>
        <artifactid>aws-android-sdk-ec2</artifactid>
        <version>[2.2.0, 2.3)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupid>com.amazonaws</groupid>
        <artifactid>aws-android-sdk-s3</artifactid>
        <version>[2.2.0, 2.3)</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can anyone provide any information on how to do functionality please? It is a major part of my app and it is really holding me back. I would really appreciate it any help at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot talk to a relational database service directly from android. You will need some sort of web server or lambda function to talk to the rds and respond you with the query output.

You can find more information on how to do that here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html

You can then use a AWS SDK for Android to invoke the lambda function that you have created.

Comment: How is this done through a facebook login rather than a register/sign in

Comment: you can use cognito identity with facebook as your identity provider to generate temporary credentials for you. You can then use these temporary credentials to invoke your lambda function via the sdk.