# Connecting Android Studio to AWS SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server, amazon-web-services, android-studio

So I'm making a time keeping app and have decided to store the data that is inputted for each day (such as storing the number of hours worked for that specific day). Its being developed in Android Studio, which I'm new to, and I want to connect it to an AWS RDS which uses SQL Server. I've managed to connect the the SQL Server database via management studio but I can't figure out how to connect the database to the app so I can add data and read from the database. How do I connect the two? Is it via the .gradle or something else?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Check out this procedure https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: see similar posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029301/how-to-store-user-information-in-relational-database-using-amazon-aws-for-facebo/37079380#37079380